# Can Husband suck the milk of his wife?

Tags: quran, fiqh, husband-wife, rada

I have search from many sites but I found mixed answers some says yes other say no. I want to ask that can husband suck the milk of his wife is it allowed in Islam or not?? Please answer with reference of Qur'an or Hadith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to majority of the scholars, drinking milk of wife is a makrooh act. It should always be avoided by all means possible because it is made for the child, not the husband to consume. There are other reasons, too, which I do not remember at the moment, but almost all scholars consider it a makrooh act. So, you must avoid drinking it. If by mistake you drink it during sucking breasts, that's OK, as you did not intend, but never try to drink it with the intention of drinking.

You can follow this link for further details on fatwa by scholars: http://islamqa.info/en/2864

Allah knows the best